# Rails AJAX reload the page. Why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I create a form:

```
<%= form_for @cover, :remote => true, :html => { :multipart => true } do |file| %>
    <%= file.file_field(:image, :class => 'choose_image', :onchange => 'this.form.submit()') %>
    <input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="<%=form_authenticity_token %>"/>
<% end %>
```

So, when I select image it uploads, OK, but after it reload the page and clear all my data. How can I repair it?

**UPDATE**

My coversController:

```
def create
    @cover = Cover.create(cover_params)

    if @cover.save
        redirect_to :back
    end
end
```

Comment: Which gem you are using to upload image? Also are you using gem like remotipart or similar?

Comment: @Dipak CarrierWave gem. I do not know about the second question =/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a browser security aspect you can not upload image/file directly through jquery ajax. You either need to create an Iframe Or you can do it with flash(SWF).

In your case `:remote => true` doing nothing it simply submitting form instead of ajax submit.

You need to add [remotipart](https://github.com/JangoSteve/remotipart) gem to achieve your desired behaviour. In this gem also you need to add `:remote => true` and form will submit in ajax way.

Comment: Sorry, but nothing. The same result. It reloads the page. I add my controller create method to my question. May be it helps

Comment: Yes there is issue in your create action. `if @cover.save
        redirect_to :back
    end` redirect_to refreshing your page remove this block. and add `create.js.erb` in view. In this view write `alert('hi')` if you get alert then everything working fine. Also include remotipart gem in your gemfile.

Comment: Hey! It works! BUT(!) I must click on submit button. How can I do that it upload after the selecting? When I write onchange='this.form.submit()' it reloads the page. What do you advice?

Comment: It should work. But if refreshing form then you should try trigger click event on button in stead form submit. Assign an ID to form  submitand them trigger click on it.